# Как сохранить веб-страницу в формат mht программно?

Tags: парсер

Решил заранее подготовить все ссылки страниц, а после сохранять их в формате .mht
Например, в .txt файле находятся все ссылки (каждая с новой строчки). Программа должна читать оттуда ссылки и сохранять в формате .mht на жесткий диск.

Можно ли это реализовать программно и какую технологию лучше использовать?

**Зачем мне это нужно?**

> Есть один интернет-магазин. С него мне нужно скачать все изображения
>   товаров. Пытался использовать jQuery через расширения Google Chrome.
>   Пытался писать приложение на C#. Но, почему-то, загружаются не все
>   картинки каталога.
>
> Вот, например эта страница: 
>   www.onlinetrade.ru/catalogue/smartfoni-c13 Здесь показано 50 товаров.
>   Ищу все конструкции "img". Скачиваю. В итоге, загружаются только
>   первые 7 картинок товаров. В итоге, решил загрузить таким способом,
>   описанным выше.

Comment: А может не первые 7, а не 10? Там на странице фильтр `10, 20, 50`. Возможно ваш парсер просто не умеет наверное нажимать на цифру 50, для фильтра? А если 7, то возможно просто получалось что берет первую картинку и идет на следующую страницу. Там берет тоже первую и т.д. Может быть просто что-то из этого не учли? Ваш парсер на `jquery` разве умеет сохранять на жесткий диск? О______О

Comment: Он у меня не переходит на другие страницы. Да, сохраняет через библиотеку xdFileStorage.js
Но, сохраняет, как кэш браузера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Точно ли сохраняет первые 7, а не 10 фото? Там на странице фильтр 10, 20, 50. Возможно ваш парсер просто не умеет наверное нажимать на цифру 50, для фильтра.
А если 7, то возможно просто получалось что берет первую картинку и идет на следующую страницу. Там берет тоже первую и т.д. Соответственно, возможно вы просто чего-то не учли.

Почему я так думаю? Потому, что урл спокойно себе парсится. Картинки (и не только) достаются без проблем.

Вот пример с использованием `php` и `Simple HTML DOM Parser`
(для использования `Simple HTML DOM Parser` конечно же надо его скачать...[ресурс](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/))

```
// Добавлять сообщения обо всех ошибках, кроме E_WARNING
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_WARNING);    
    include './domParser/simple_html_dom.php';

    class DomParser {
        public $url = '';
        public $imgHost = '';   
        public $returnVal = 0;

        public function __construct($urlParse, $imgHostUrl) {
            $this->url = $urlParse;
            $this->imgHost = $imgHostUrl;           
        }


        public function getImages($_data) {         
            $i = 1;
            $data = $_data ? $_data : file_get_html($this->url);

            if ($data->innertext != '') {               
                foreach ($data->find('div.catalog__displayedItem') as $a) {         
                    foreach ($a->find('.catalog__displayedItem__columnFoto img') as $img) {
                        echo '<img src="' . $this->imgHost . $img->src .'" />';                     

                        $imgExt = explode('.', $img->src);                      

                        // Это для добавления картинки себе в папку
                        // Закоментировал в фиддле
                        if ($image = file_get_contents($this->imgHost . $img->src)) {
                            //file_put_contents('./images/' . $i . '.' . end($imgExt), $image);                         
                        }                       
                    }

                    $i++;                           
                }

                echo '<br /><br />';

                $this->getNextPage($data, 'getImages');
                $data->clear();
                unset($data);
            }
        }


        public function getNextPage($data, $repeatFunctionName) {           
            // сделал пока чтобы много циклов не делал не нагружал              
            if ($this->returnVal >= 2)
                return;

            if ($data->innertext != '') {   
                $this->returnVal++;

                foreach ($data->find('.catalogItemList__paginator a') as $a) {                                          
                    $str = iconv("windows-1251", "UTF-8", $a->title);

                    if (mb_strpos(strtolower($str), 'ледующие', 0, 'UTF-8') !== false) {                    
                        $page = explode('?', $a->href);             
                        $data_inner_link = file_get_html($this->url . '?' . end($page));
                        $this->$repeatFunctionName($data_inner_link);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $url = 'http://www.onlinetrade.ru/catalogue/smartfoni-c13/';
    $imgHost = 'http://www.onlinetrade.ru';
    $parser = new DomParser($url, $imgHost);
    $parser->getImages(null);   

    /*  
    $url = 'http://www.onlinetrade.ru/catalogue/smartfoni-c13/';
    $imgHost = 'http://www.onlinetrade.ru';
    $data = file_get_html($url);
    $i = 1;

    function getImages($data) {
        global $imgHost;
        global $i;

        if ($data->innertext!='') {         
            foreach($data->find('div.catalog__displayedItem') as $a) {          
                foreach ($a->find('.catalog__displayedItem__columnFoto img') as $img) {
                    echo '<img src="' . $imgHost . $img->src .'" />';                                       
                    $imgExt = explode('.', $img->src);                      

                    // Это для добавления картинки себе в папку
                    // Закоментировал в фиддле
                    if ($image = file_get_contents($imgHost . $img->src)) {
                        file_put_contents('./images/' . $i . '.' . end($imgExt), $image);
                    }                   
                }

                $i++;                           
            }

            echo '<br /><br />';

            getNextPage($data);
            $data->clear();
            unset($data);
        }
    }

    $return = 0;
    function getNextPage($data) {
        global $url;
        global $return;

        // сделал пока чтобы много циклов не делал не нагружал              
        if ($return >= 2)
            return;

        if($data->innertext != ''){         
            $return++;

            foreach($data->find('.catalogItemList__paginator a') as $a){                                            
                $str = iconv("windows-1251", "UTF-8", $a->title);               

                if (mb_strpos(strtolower($str), 'ледующие', 0, 'UTF-8') !== false) {                    
                    $page = explode('?', $a->href);             
                    $data_inner_link = file_get_html($url . '?' . end($page));
                    getImages($data_inner_link);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //getImages($data);

    */
```

Вариант использования класса и вариант обычный через функции (закоментированы ниже)

Потрогать можно [Здесь](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ehvv-jgyp)

На данный момент специально установлено ограничение на парсинг только первых 3-х страниц (по 10 товаров), чтобы не грузить фиддл  и закоменчена строка с `file_put_contents` потому что фиддл не пропускает, что логично)))

вот пруф сохранения: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И там еще много внизу...

Как вариант можно и наверное лучше использовать (касаемо `php`) `cURL`

**cURL** - свободная служебная программа командной строки, позволяющая взаимодействовать с множеством различных серверов по множеству различных протоколов с синтаксисом URL.

---

Этот код просто скорее в целях показать, что всё работает, можно скачать и что у вас, скорее всего, где-то в коде ошибка.

Не является, скорее всего, мой ответ ответом, но, возможно, этот код будет чем-то полезен и захотите как-то переделать под нужды. Нежели сохранять `mht`. Хотя памяти он будет кушать много.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!
Очень помогли! Буду разбираться!

Answer (score 2):

Для программного создания mht:

- [C# source code for generating MHT files from an URL](http://code.google.com/p/url2mhtml/)
- CDO.Message COM-объект, реализующий [IMessage interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Из JavaScript попробуйте вызвать `print(document.body.innerHTML);`
или `document.execCommand('SaveAs','true','http://...')`

Comment: Спасибо, поизучаю и эту документацию.