# Как сохранить изображения с сайта на C#?

Tags: c#, .net, парсер

Как преобразовать этот код на C#, чтобы сохранялись все изображения с этого URL: http://www.onlinetrade.ru/catalogue/tsifrovie_fotoapparati-c5

Сейчас, программа ищет все конструкции с "imgsrc". В итоге, почему-то сохраняет не все изображения. А мне нужно, чтобы сохранялись только те изображения, которые находятся в div'е с классом "catalog__displayedItem__columnFoto".

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplicationTest
{
    public static class Parser
    {
        //*Парсим*теги*изображений
        private static readonly Regex ImgRegex = new Regex(@"\<img.+?src=\""(?<imgsrc>.+?)\"".+?\>",
            RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.Compiled);

        private static void Main()
        {
            var urls = new[] {
                "http://www.onlinetrade.ru/catalogue/tsifrovie_fotoapparati-c5",
               // "http://www.onlinetrade.ru/catalogue/tsifrovie_fotoapparati_so_smennoy_optikoy-c268",
               // "http://www.onlinetrade.ru/catalogue/tsifrovie_zerkalnie_fotoapparati-c4",
            };

            // Загружаем параллельно все сайты
            Parallel.ForEach(urls, DownloadFiles);

            Console.WriteLine("Загрузка закончена");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void DownloadFiles(string site)
        {
            string data;
            Console.WriteLine(site);
            Console.WriteLine("Загрузка страницы");
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                using (Stream stream = client.OpenRead(site))
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        data = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Загрузка картинок");
            // Создаём директорию под картинки\
            string directory = "Downoloads";
                if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
                }

            ImgRegex.Matches(data)
                .Cast<Match>()
                //*Данный*из*группы*регулярного*выражения
                .Select(m => m.Groups["imgsrc"].Value.Trim())
                // Удаляем повторяющиеся
                .Distinct()
                //*Добавляем*название*сайта,*если*ссылки*относительные
                .Select(url => ("http://onlinetrade.ru") + url)
                //*Получаем*название*картинки
                .Select(url => new { url, name = url.Split(new[] { '/' }).Last() })
                //*Проверяем*его
                .Where(arg => Regex.IsMatch(arg.name, @"[^\s\/]\.(jpg|png|gif|bmp)\z"))
                // Параллелим на 6 потоков
                .AsParallel()
                .WithDegreeOfParallelism(50)
                // Загружаем асинхронно
                .ForAll(value =>
                {
                    string savePath = Path.Combine(directory, value.name);
                    using (WebClient localClient = new WebClient())
                    {
                        localClient.DownloadFile(value.url, savePath);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} загружен", value.name);
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Скорее всего регулярка неточная.

Comment: вместо `\""` укажите `\"`

Comment: А как это повлияет на работу приложения?

Comment: @program23 _"А как это повлияет на работу приложения?"_ -- у вас в вопросе сказано "почему-то сохраняет не все". я прочел первый коммент и поэтому. А вообще вместо Regex для парсинга html используйте например HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: @Stack да, сейчас как раз  пытаюсь освоить эту библиотеку.
Но, опять же, не могу правильно написать фильтр:
`HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='catalog__displayedItem__columnFoto']/img");`

Не ищет ничего.

Comment: _"мне нужно ... изображения которые находятся в div'е"_ -- фактически нужны изображения товаров. у них в src есть одинаковая часть url'а, и чтобы не возиться с div'ами можно найти все img, и отфильтровать по части url'а. см. [мой ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/478348/196972)

Comment: Вы уже знаете, что парсить HTML регулярками гиблое дело?

Comment: @VladD сразу понял, что регулярки - это боль.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cs
using System.Text;
using System.Net;

var d = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

// тут загружаем html ...

foreach (var img in Images(d, "/img/items/")) {
    Console.WriteLine(img.Url.Segments.Last() + " " + img.Title);
    // скачиваем рисунок с сайта и записываем в файл
    using (var c = new WebClient())
      c.DownloadFile(img.Url, @"c:\temp\" + img.Title + ".jpg");
}

static IEnumerable<Img> Images(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc, string urlContains) {
  foreach (var img in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")) {
    var t = img.ParentNode.Attributes["title"];
    var s = img.Attributes["src"].Value;
    if (s.Contains(urlContains))
      yield return new Img { Url = new Uri(s), Title = (t != null ? t.Value : "") };
  }
}

class Img {
    public string Title;
    public Uri Url;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    var source = webClient.DownloadString(@"http://www.onlinetrade.ru/catalogue/tsifrovie_fotoapparati-c5");
    var document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    document.LoadHtml(source);
    var imageList = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img").Select(x => x.Attributes["src"]).Select(link => string.Format(@"http://www.onlinetrade.ru{0}", link.Value)).ToList();
    // ваши действия со списком ссылок.
```

Comment: Все равно выводит не все изображения:
[Скриншот](http://i.imgur.com/UvGpnLH.png)

Comment: А  HtmlAgilityPack может сохранять загруженный сайт на жесткий диск в формате html? Чтобы создавалась еще папка под каждый html со всеми ресурсами.

Если да, то такой способ сохранения изображений тоже подошел бы.

Comment: @program23 для сохранения сайта с ресурсами можно воспользоваться HTTrack

Comment: не сохраняет он все картинки и слишком долго перебирает все.
Также пробовал и Offline Explorer, Teleport, Bulk Image, PicaLoader.

Пробовал на php + simple_html_dom запарсить все картинки. Он работает, находит все фотографии, но очень медленный. Вот в этой [теме](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/476798/Как-сохранить-веб-страницу-в-формат-mht-программно/476860#476860), Алексей Шиманский помогал мне.