# Как на C# сохранить веб-страницу в html файл с папкой ресурсов?

Tags: c#, .net, парсер, htmlagilitypack

В браузере, когда сохраняешь страницу, можно выбрать "Сохранить страницу (полностью)". В итоге: сохраняется .html файл и папка со всеми ресурсами.
Подойдет ли HtmlAgilityPack ? И, если да, то как это реализовывать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

> Подойдет ли HtmlAgilityPack?

С помощью HtmlAgilityPack в html можно найти все теги img. Для каждого прочесть атрибут src, в котором может быть url рисунка или `data:image/svg+xml,<svg....`.
После этого надо скачать рисунки, сохранить их в файлы. А в html заменить значения src на имена файлов. И сохранить html в файле.

Пример для поиска и скачивания рисунков - [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/476984/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c#comment546274_476984).

---

Возможна следующая ситуация: в браузере изображения видны, а если загрузить страницу и парсить ее в HtmlAgilityPack, то части изображений нет.
Причина в том, что когда страница загружена в веб-браузер, то изображения могут подгружаться JavaScript'ом.

Comment: Проблема в том, что находятся не все src. 
[В этой теме я уже об этом писал](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/476984/Как-сохранить-изображения-с-сайта-на-c/477185?noredirect=1#comment543556_477185)

Comment: @program23 _"находятся не все src."_ -- это возможно если изображения подгружаются javascript'ом. я дополнил ответ.