# Вопрос о SelectSingleNode

Tags: c#, .net, парсер

Учусь парсить. 
Как через `SelectSingleNode` (HTML Agility Pack) достать все `p` или только через `SelectNodes`?
На даный момент у меня кроме `p` ещё и 1 `<div>` со скриптом хватает.
Как можно его исключить? Спасибо!

```
 var nodeText = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/article[1]");
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можно SelectNodes и добавить /p. Всё равно вам нужна коллекция, наверно?

Comment: _"/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/article[1]"_ -- вот так (указывать весь путь) не надо. чтобы найти все p надо SelectNodes("//p")

Comment: если нужен только один тег, то вместо SelectSingleNode(...) можно указать SelectNodes(...).First();

Comment: @Stack палка о двух концах. На деле, надо уникальное имя класса\ещё какую то фигню, из которой потом читаются p.

Comment: @Monk не всегда надо искать сверху-вниз. недавно был [пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/476984/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c/478348#478348). оказалось проще найти все рис. и отфильтровать их по фрагменту урла. а пытались найти рис. сверху-вниз и неполучалась

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, есть несколько тегов `<p>`, но надо найти только те, что находятся внутри тега `article` с атрибутом `class="prose"`.

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(@"
        <html><head /><body>
        <p>start></p>
        <article class='prose'><p>p1</p><p>p2</p></article>
        <p>end</p>
        </body></html>");

foreach (var p in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//article[@class='prose']/p")) {
    Console.WriteLine(p.InnerText);
}
```

результат

```
p1
p2
```